# How to control the spatial discretization of a 3D Region object

Tags: regions

I am using constructive geometry to build up a complex 3D shape. I do so by combining Region objects of Graphics3D[] primitives using RegionUnion[] and RegionDifference[]. Here is the code that I use:

```
tower = 2000;
substrate = 100;
radiusHole = 500;
radiusRim = 600;
radiusBase = 1000;

origin = {0, 0, 0};
base = {0, 0, substrate};
tip = {0, 0, tower + substrate};

hole = Region[Cylinder[{base, tip}, radiusHole]];
rim = Region[Cylinder[{base, tip}, radiusRim]];
disk = Region[Cylinder[{origin, base}, radiusBase]];

r = RegionUnion[RegionDifference[rim, hole], disk];
Show[r]
```

[image: The output from Show[r]]

Apparently, Mathematica is using a coarse discretization for the objects, so that they get truncated. Any idea on how to prevent this, or control it, would be fantastic!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. You can accept an answer by pressing the arrow next to the answer. The arrow will turn green. It enables visitors to the page to locate solutions to similar problems. We all hope to see you frequently at the site.

Answer (score 5):

Try `DiscretizeRegion` in the definition of `hole`,`rim` and `disk`:

```
hole = Region[Cylinder[{base, tip},radiusHole]] // DiscretizeRegion;
rim = Region[Cylinder[{base, tip},radiusRim]] // DiscretizeRegion;
disk = Region[Cylinder[{origin, base},radiusBase]] //DiscretizeRegion;

r=RegionUnion[RegionDifference[rim,hole],disk];
```

Show[r]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, a perfect solution that covers my most urgent needs!

Answer (score 1):

The powerful `OpenCascadeLink` can handle the surface independently and it is easy to be use in `NDSolve`.

```
tower = 2000;
substrate = 100;
radiusHole = 500;
radiusRim = 600;
radiusBase = 1000;
origin = {0, 0, 0};
base = {0, 0, substrate};
tip = {0, 0, tower + substrate};
reg1 = Cylinder[{base, tip}, radiusHole];
reg2 = Cylinder[{base, tip}, radiusRim];
reg3 = Cylinder[{origin, base}, radiusBase];
reg = RegionUnion[reg3, RegionDifference[reg2, reg1]];

Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"];
shape = OpenCascadeShape[reg];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[shape, 
   "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {"LinearDeflection" -> 0.001}];
groups = bmesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"];
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]];
colors = ColorData["BrightBands"][#] & /@ temp;
bmesh["Wireframe"[
  "MeshElementStyle" -> (Directive[EdgeForm[], FaceForm[#]] & /@ 
     colors)]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. I was not aware of this functionality – you never cease to learn something new :)